# Remove a modal ViewController from ram SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in Swift and IOS programing

I want to know how I remove my modal ViewController from memory ram.

This kind that I use to open.

```
 let vc = self.storybordar?.instantieteViewController(withIndentifier:"indentifier") as UIViewController 

 self.present(vc,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

And I remove so

```
self.dissmiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
```

My controller until closed but my memory not change

What happinig is when I open my modal my memory increases and when a I close my memory doesn't decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift uses automatic reference counting for memory management. Objects will be released from memory if no references to them exist anymore.

You can remove a reference by setting a variable referencing the object to nil.

```
vc = nil
```

or by using weak references whenever possible.

If you dismiss the view controller, you have to make sure, there are no references left or it will not be released from memory.

Also, iOS may keep some data around. Just make sure, that memory usage does not grow significantly on subsequent presentations of your view controller. Only then you may have a reference cycle.

Comment: I already resolved my problem.

I used removeFromSuperView()

Thanks a Lot!